# How to implement voucher redemption from storefront in Hybris 5.7?

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud

I want to implement voucher redemption from storefront in Hybris.

From wiki i got to know that there are already OOTB api defined by hybris.

Can anyone tell me what are the exact services or facade i should call for voucher redemption and cart recalculation after successful redemption ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can have a look on VoucherService.In this we have

```
boolean redeemVoucher(String arg0, CartModel arg1) throws JaloPriceFactoryException;
```

This will take care of redemption.

Comment: this will apply voucher but what about refreshing cart total ??

Comment: This will take care of cart calculations...if it is ajax call you have to write your own logic to show it in frontend